# Как обработать ошибку в aiogram не закрытый тег HTML

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу словить ошибку:
*aiogram.utils.exceptions.CantParseEntities: Can't parse entities: can't find end tag corresponding to start tag*

То есть, когда бот отправляет сообщение с **parse_mode HTML** и какой-то тег некорректен (не открыт или не закрыт) нужно обработать в:

```
@dp.errors_handler(exception=aiogram.utils.exceptions.BotBlocked)
async def error_bot_blocked(update: types.Update, exception: BotBlocked):
```

Comment: Эм.. Почему бы не воспользоваться try except ?

Comment: Много где в коде это деталь нужна.

Comment: @RNB, напишите одну функцию с одним параметром(само сообщение) - обработайте и верните то что вам нужно. а дальше если отправляете сообщение -> send_message(chat_id, MY_FUCTION(message.chat_id)). Думаю это возможно, в функции и будет происходить try except. По скорости не ударит(надеюсь)